# No such host is known

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to develop a website and when I am trying to create a connection and insert data in to the database `mysql_connect()` error makes me crazy. The error is below:

> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed:No such host is known.

If it is helpful, I am using `localhost` as a host name. What should I do to resolve this ?

Comment: insert localhost inside your hosts file?

Comment: Either properly configure your name resolving or use `127.0.0.1` for connection instead of _localhost_. Also please note that `mysql_*()` functions have been removed as of PHP 7, so it is advisable to use `mysqli_*()` OR `PDO` instead.

Comment: this is  happened when mysql host url is incorrect. check your mysql host is working

Comment: SHow us your PHP code

Answer (score 0):

Instead IPV4:
127.0.0.1

try with IPV6:
::1